# SuperTest Session not staying logged in between post and get calls to Express App

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, passport.js, supertest

I am trying to do integration tests using Jest and SuperTest on a Node.js/Express app. All route testing is going well with the exception of testing protected routes. I am using Passport with a local strategy for authentication. I cannot get SuperTest to persist a session within a test.

For example:

```js
const request = require('supertest')
const { app } = require('../app')

describe('Login route testing', async () => {
    test('POST /logout after logging in with valid credentials redirects to "/" route.', async () => {
        const agent = request.agent(app)
    
        // Getting '/login' works. Most pages will redirect here if not already authenticated.
        const res1 = await agent
            .post('/login')
            .send({ email: 'test@test.com', password: 'this_is_the_password' })
            .expect(302)
            .expect('Location', '/')
            .expect('set-cookie', /sessionID=/)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.header['set-cookie'][0])
                    // Logs this: 'sessionID=s%3ASA-ECqLUB0xF6YECYuphrWsE30WJBWny.Ktt%2FqypTP2MAtPLXK6ItC%2B8yf2c7FUZp3CpfIdwvGZs; Domain=localhost; Path=/; HttpOnly'
                agent.jar.setCookie(res.headers['set-cookie'][0])
            })
    
        // The above test passes as expected. Credentials are authenticated,
        // it redirects back to the homepage, and everything is fine.
        // Manual testing confirms this works as well.
    
        // At this point, the agent should have this session persisted,
        // and going to the homepage should work.
    
        const res2 = await agent.get('/').expect(200)
    
        // However, this test fails. It returns a 302 status, will try to redirect to '/login',
        // and has no data from the previous session.
    })
})
```

I have tried several solutions.

- [Persist express app session in mocha and supertest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864247/persist-express-app-session-in-mocha-and-supertest) suggested moving the `const agent = request.agent(app)` outside the describe block. I got the same result.
- [supertest agent doesn't seem to persist sessions in node.js express.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842106/supertest-agent-doesnt-seem-to-persist-sessions-in-node-js-express-js-app) had issues with asynchronous code, which I don't believe is going on in my case.

I'm at a standstill now. How do I fix this issue?